# Simple get range script in google script failing due to server error at Line 42 - not sure why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so I am a newbie to programming as well as google scripts. I have just started writing a very basic script to compile data from various different tabs into a single new "home" tab - all within the same spreadsheet. When running the script I get "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 42, file "Code")" and I am not sure why. When debugging I can see that the correct values are being extracted.

Code is below and any help would be much appreciated. I may also be going about this in a really inefficient way so any advice would be a big help.
Thanks

```
var SHEET_HOME = 'Home';
var SHEET_CCSF = 'CCSF2015';
var SHEET_FRANCE = 'FranceClusters';
var SHEET_SCOT = 'Scotland';
var SHEET_CCASIA = 'CCAsia2015';
var SHEET_NORDIC = 'NordicGames2015';
var SHEET_NORWAY = 'Norway';
var SHEET_GAMESCOM ='Gamescom2015';

function UpdateData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var home = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_HOME);
 var ccsf = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_CCSF);
 var scot = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_SCOT);
 var ccasia = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_CCASIA);
 var nordic = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NORDIC);
 var norway = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NORWAY);
 var gamescom = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_GAMESCOM);


 // Determine length of each database
 var length1 = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_CCSF).getRange("N1").getValue();
 var length2 = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_SCOT).getRange("N1").getValue();
 var length3 = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_CCASIA).getRange("N1").getValue();
 var length4 = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NORDIC).getRange("N1").getValue();
 var length5 = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NORWAY).getRange("N1").getValue();
 var length6 = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_GAMESCOM).getRange("N1").getValue();  

 // Provide starting row for each additional range of data
 var start2 = 4+length1;
 var start3 = start2 + length2;
 var start4 = start3 + length3;
 var start5 = start4 + length4;
 var start6 = start5 + length5; 

 // Select required range in each db
 var range1 = ccsf.getRange("A2:L"+length1);
 var range2 = scot.getRange("A2:L"+length2);
 var range3 = ccasia.getRange("A2:L"+length3);
 var range4 = nordic.getRange("A2:L"+length4);
 var range5 = norway.getRange("A2:L"+length5);
 var range6 = gamescom.getRange("A2:L"+length6);

 // Fill Home tab with all data
 range1.copyValuesToRange(home, 1, 12, 4, length1);
 range2.copyValuesToRange(home, 1, 12, start2, length2);
 range3.copyValuesToRange(home, 1, 12, start3, length3);
 range4.copyValuesToRange(home, 1, 12, start4, length4);
 range5.copyValuesToRange(home, 1, 12, start5, length5); 
 range6.copyValuesToRange(home, 1, 12, start6, length6);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the different *length var's* don't get you the length but the value of the indicated range. You will have to add .length if it is the length of the value you are after...

```
var length1 = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_CCSF).getRange("N1").getValue().length;

....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply however in this case the value of the range "N1" is a numeric value. N1 is actually a countA function calculating the length of the range within the spreadsheet. Therefore adding length here would give an undefined value.

Comment: Just to add to this - the function works for range1 and range2. if I only include those lines then the function works and pulls in data correctly. However it fails for range3 onwards